# Script with network settings

Tags: ip, root, gateway

Hey there I want to write a script that will change the network profile settings (ifconfig, /etc/resolv.comf). Let the script retrieve and display the contents of the file with network profiles to root. The format of the database file will be in the form of: IP, IP Mask, Gateway. I've already done something but don't know if it's correct.

```
#!/bin/bash 
IP=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
IPMask=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep Mask | cut -d":" -f4) 
Gateway=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}') 
echo "IP is : $IP" 
echo "IP Mask is: $IPMask"
echo Gateway is: $Gateway"
```

The part I don't understand how to do is - Root interactively selects the network profile (by number), which is then activated. Any help please?